# Larger Method Program. Please read the body so you understand what it is I need to write a basic java code for

Tags: java

Write a method called larger that accepts two floating-point parameters (of type double) and returns true if the first parameter is greater than the second, and false otherwise.

I need help writing code in java (very basic java, not complicated) that accomplishes this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean larger(double a, double b) {
    return a > b;
}
```

## Demo:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(larger(15, 10));
        System.out.println(larger(5, 10));
    }

    static boolean larger(double a, double b) {
        return a > b;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
false
```

## Demo using user inputs:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double d1, d2;
        System.out.print("Enter the first floating point number: ");
        d1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter the second floating point number: ");
        d2 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(larger(d1, d2));

        // An example of further processing based on the returned value
        System.out.println(larger(d1, d2) ? d1 : d2 + " is greater");
    }

    static boolean larger(double a, double b) {
        return a > b;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the first floating point number: 4.5
Enter the second floating point number: 9.2
false
9.2 is greater
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter the first floating point number: 50.5
Enter the second floating point number: 2.5
true
50.5 is greater
```

Comment: Is that all there is to the program?

Comment: @LeonardDaVinci - I've added a demo of the same in my answer. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Say I want to take in user input for the two values, how would I go about that?

Comment: @LeonardDaVinci - I think that you should at least attempt to do your own homework. It's bad enough that this fella did most of it already.

Comment: I was not understanding how to do it, so I was asking for help.

Comment: @LeonardDaVinci It is usually a good idea to attempt to do the task, and then to show us what you have done, and where you are stuck - good luck.